# Can Ghostscript start numbering pages from zero?

Tags: ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript to convert a multi-page PDF to individual JPEG files and can get it to output the files numbered like `page_%03d.jpg`.

But it always starts at *page_001.jpg* and I need it to start numbering the output files starting from *page_000.jpg*.

Is there a setting I can use to get Ghostscript to start at zero or am I going to have to rename all the files after processing?

Answer (score 9):

Hmm... tricky question. I don't think there is a way to tweak the `-sOutputFile=string_%03d.jpeg`-syntax to start at zero.

### However, what about trying it with a little workaround?

The trick is to use 2 passes for processing your PDF file

1. ***First pass:*** make processing by Ghostscript start with page 2 through the end.    Your page numbering for this pass will still start at 1. But each consecutive page will now have a filename which is offset by -1.
2. ***Second pass:*** make processing by Ghostscript stop after page 1, and hardcode the output filename to include your desired zero numbering.

Here is are the two commands spelled out explicitely:

1. ***First pass:***

   ```
   gswin32c.exe ^
      -o c:/path/to/output/page_%03d.jpg ^
      -sDEVICE=jpeg ^
      [...more options as needed...] ^
      -dFirstPage=2 ^
      -f c:/path/to/input.pdf
   ```

   This will result in:

   ```
    first page processed, page 2 ....... named as page_001.jpg
   second page processed, page 3 ....... named as page_002.jpg
    third page processed, page 4 ....... named as page_003.jpg
   [...]
   ```
2. ***Second pass:***

   ```
   gswin32c.exe ^
      -o c:/path/to/output/page_000.jpg ^
      -sDEVICE=jpeg ^
      [...more options as needed...] ^
      -dLastPage=1 ^
      -f c:/path/to/input.pdf
   ```

   This will result in:

   ```
     only page processed, page 1 ....... named as page_000.jpg
   ```

## Voila!

This little trick can spare you a lot of work renaming all the pages. It's surely faster as soon as you have more than a few pages to process. And of course, this basic approach can easily be scripted.

Enjoy...

## ☺

Answer (score 0):

To close this question, i will answer myself: no ghostscript cannot start numbering from zero. I had to rename all the files after ghostscript was done processing.